# Why does JSDoc throw a TypeError while processing a valid file

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a dojo class with some JSDoc tags in it. The JavaScript runs fine, without errors, so it's certainly a valid file.

The class is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8JpCR/

When I try to run JSDoc on it, to generate docs, I get:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3785)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3763)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3791)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3810)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3823)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1508)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__projects_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_path_js_30._c_anonymous_2(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__projects_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_path_js_30.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__projects_jsdoc_templates_default_publish_js_43._c_anonymous_26(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__projects_jsdoc_templates_default_publish_js_43.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1._c_main_3(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1._c_script_0(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:426)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3178)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._projects_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.evaluateScript(Main.java:654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFileSecure(Main.java:552)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFile(Main.java:507)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processSource(Main.java:499)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFiles(Main.java:215)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main$IProxy.run(Main.java:134)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:521)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:535)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.exec(Main.java:198)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.java:174)
```

The proliferation of JSDocs docs ([here](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list), [here](http://usejsdoc.org/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags)) aren't much use.

Has anyone else seen this error? Did you get to the bottom of it? Any pointers on resources that are up to date and accurate for JSDoc?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the master branch of JSDoc